# How do I tell when a configuration change is happening in Froyo?

Tags: android

In my app, I want a media file to play, and to keep playing if the user rotates the screen (destroying the Activity), but I want it to stop playing if the user moves to a different Activity or another Activity appears over this one, they press the back button, whatever.

I believe there's an API for this in Honeycomb, but I need something that will work in Android 2.2.

I'd rather not use onConfigurationChanged to handle all the configuration changes myself--that sounds like a lot of work and potential bugs--and the issue with onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() is that it doesn't run until after onStop fires--but onPause would be the logical place to pause the media, if appropriate.

Is there a way, in onPause, to tell if the Activity is being paused for a configuration change versus another reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution has at least one potential problem.

According to Android documentation:

> Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()).

Testing for a change in rotation only handles one case.  Since this is likely to be the most common cause of configuration change, it's an OK solution.  But what if you could handle all cases, existing or added in some future version of Android, without the overhead of handling configuration yourself?

Updated to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`.  Android docs have this to say about it:

> Called by the system, as part of destroying an activity due to a configuration change, when it is known that a new instance will immediately be created for the new configuration.

Also changed chain to super.onDestroy() to happen after stopping media, but not entirely sure about that.  Guess it depends on what stopping media means, and what effect destroying may have on stopping media.

```
private Boolean mConfigurationChange = false;

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    mConfigurationChange = true;
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (!mConfigurationChange) {
        // Code to stop media file goes here.
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: An interesting idea, Julian, thank you for the detailed example. Once I add android:configChanges="orientation" to the relevant Activity in the manifest, it takes effect, but not as I expected. onConfigurationChanged DOES fire... but onPause/onStop/onDestroy are never called. So that's one way to get around the issue of "rotating the screen destroys the Activity" but not in a Google-recommended way. Thanks though!

Comment: See updated answer. Doesn't involve change to manifest and onDestroy() still called.

Comment: The new answer seems to work! OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance fires after onStop and before onDestroy, and with this code onDestroy accurately can tell whether it's shutting down for a configuration change or not. Thanks!

Comment: :) You're welcome.  I actually came across your question because I was also trying to figure out how to detect that an activity was about to be destroyed and recreated due to a configuration change.  So it helped us both.

Answer (score 7):

Prior to Honeycomb, `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` as mentioned in the accepted answer is the best way to do this.

Starting with Honeycomb, that's deprecated, but there is a much simpler way: call `isChangingConfigurations()` instead, during any of your `onPause()`/`onStop()`/`onDestroy()`.

Finally, if using the support library FragmentActivity (
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) on pre-Honeycomb, `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is declared final, but you can override `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` instead for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the answer to my own question!

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  Display display; 
  int originalRotation;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
      originalRotation = display.getRotation();
  }

  public boolean endingDueToConfigurationChanging() {
   int newRotation = display.getRotation();
   return (newRotation != originalRotation);
  }
}
```

Display.getRotation() is designed to return a constant indicating whether the device is 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees off its natural rotation. However, when the device is rotated, this value is updated before the activity ends--it's actually updated as early as in onPause()! So if you compare the value in onPause() (the new value) with the one in onCreate() (the original value) then you know the Activity it shutting down due to a screen rotation or not.

Comment: What uses "endingDueToConfigurationChanging"? I thought maybe this was some API Android calls and if you return false it won't end after all, but apparently it's not, and I can't tell how you are using it.

Comment: That was five years and several companies ago... I'm afraid I have no idea. I'm guessing I accidentally left out some code calling endingDueToConfigurationChanging. Oh well. There are better answers now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try listening for the ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED intent and setting an internal flag indicating the pause is from a configuration change.

I'm not sure if you will receive the intent in time or that you will be guaranteed it will arrive in time as it is probably asynchronous.  Might be worth a try though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `View#onConfigurationChanged` in case its applicable in your case(i.e - you have a view for your media player and have a reference to it in the view).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, iLate, but as I stated in my original question, if I used onConfigurationChanged then I would be replacing Android's handling of rotation with my own code--meaning I would have to manually change the layout, etc. That's a lot of work to do for my simple goal of knowing if configuration is changing or not.

Comment: I'm telling you to override View#onConfigurationChanged, but not Activity#onConfigurationChanged. This method gets called everytime <strong>before</strong> your activity has been recreated after configuration change, no matter what you have specified in your manifest file.

Comment: A complete example may help me understand better. I think you're suggesting making a custom View class and overriding onConfigurationChanged there? It doesn't work unless I add android:configChanges="orientation" to the relevant Activity in the manifest, and then onPause/onStop/onDestroy are never called anyway. Thanks though.