# Does the activity have the "orientation" flag in the manifest?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm trying to find information on this and I haven't found much. Is it possible to, programmatically, determine whether the application has the android:configChanges="orientation" at runtime?

So, if I have this line in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name="android.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

How do I find out if that "orientation" option is actually there. Since I'm working in a library I do not always know the state of the manifest. Besides, at this stage I don't really care what's the orientation of the device, only if the application knows that it has to execute my onConfigurationChange() function.

I don't want to change its orientation, I just want to know whether the flag is there.

I know that the configChange option is there so I can use onConfigurationChange in my code, but at the moment I don't want to override any default behavior but I also don't want to wait for the event to launch to find out if the flag is set.

If the answer is for Monodroid that would be best, but answers in java are welcomed.

Comment: "rights to rotate" and "configChanges=orientation", have nothing to do with one another. Your question is very unclear, please describe better what you are trying to achieve with that and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Edited. I hope that's enough, else I'll change it again

Answer (score 0):

[Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369722/julian) posted a pretty good answer to this. Although they're specifically speaking to Froyo, the answer is also applicable in other Android versions.

> [How do I tell when a configuration change is happening in Froyo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314935/how-do-i-tell-when-a-configuration-change-is-happening-in-froyo/8886588#8886588)