# Differentiate between closing the app and turning the device

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, landscape-portrait

is it possible to tell these 2 states appart? close an app vs. turn the device into landscape/portrait. Because i won´t lose any data if the user closes the app but if he is bored and, lets say hes really bored, turns his device several times i won´t have this Safe/Load process all the time.

I´ve overwritten the on... methods to understand the android livecycle but i see no difference in behavior between turning the device and closing the activity.

im open for suggestions or a discussion.

I guess i need to explain my problem. I had the idea to safe data in the onPause method, but the problem is to differentiate between closing (where it should safe the data) and turning the device ( where it shouldn´t safe) don´t want to eat the battery.

Should i force the user to select landscape or portrait mode if he enters this special activity? or make it possible via a menu?.. i mean this would be a less smooth experiance for the user but easier for me somehow.

Comment: define close an app ... as there is no such concept in android

Comment: there is no need to reload the data when the orientation changes...that's why `onCreate` has an argument called `savedInstanceState`

Comment: what do you mean with define it? something like if(oldactivity=newactivity) {onresume()} else { finsih();)}??

Comment: @Daniel Puiu i don´t have a problem with reloading.. i have the problem that i need to avoid datalose but also the unneccesary acces to the db.

Comment: reloading data because of configuration changes seems to be unnecessary access to a database. so, you want to avoid saving data because someone could change the configuration a lot ? you might do that by keeping a flag that tells you that a configuration change will happen and save your data in `onDestroy`...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314935/how-do-i-tell-when-a-configuration-change-is-happening-in-froyo

Comment: so it seems like `isChangingConfigurations` (api level 11) will help you even in `onPause`

Comment: ok, but when i turn the device my activity is paused-stopped-destroyed. and lets say the user is turning the device 10 times, my db get´s accesed 10 times with "safe all data from the special aktivity","give all data from the special activity".. 10 times which is only at 10% cpu ussage each time the db get´s accesed. but i want to avoid it, if it is  possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick!

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isChangingConfigurations()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"got turned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"need to safe data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //safe data
    }

}
```